# Directory path calls, strange behaviour

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, path

I have an ajax request that I'm trying to call a specific file from which is located at:

```
ROOT/admin/functions/upload/filename.php
```

And the page making the request from is located at:

```
ROOT/admin/customers/123
```

Which is modified through htaccess from

```
ROOT/admin/customer.php?id=123
```

I have tried every combination of paths I could think of but I get some strange behaviours for example when I use

```
../functions/upload/filename.php
```

It looks for the file in

```
ROOT/functions/uploads/filename.php
```

And when I use

```
functions/upload/filename.php
```

It looks for the file in

```
ROOT/admin/customers/functions/uploads/filename.php
```

So I tried

```
../admin/functions/upload/filename.php
```

And it looks in

```
ROOT/admin/admin/functions/upload/filename.php
```

I'm pulling my hair out here, has anyone got any ideas as to what this might be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, James.

Comment: Why don't you use an absolute path like `/functions/uploads/filename.php`? That would make your file accessible from any sub-directory.

Comment: I have had to change all of my PHP include/require relative paths for working on XAMMP but I tried it just to see and it looked for the file in ROOT/functions/upload/filename.php

Comment: There are two kinds of absolute paths: On the servers side, the file system, and on the client side, relative to the root of the web-server. What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the browser knows NOTHING about your server-side paths, and it only has the path you see in the address bar, e.g.

```
http://example.com/ROOT/admin/customers/123
```

then if your ajax code looks like

```
$.ajax('functions/foo/bar.php');
```

Then the ajax call will be requesting

```
http://example.com/ROOT/admin/customers/123/functions/foo/bar.php
```

Similarly, adding `../` just strips off levels of the source page's address:

```
$.ajax('../../functions/foo/bar.php');
```

results in

```
http://example.com/ROOT/admin/customers/123/../../functions/foo/bar.php
                                         ^-A-^
                                 ^-------B------^

http://example.com/ROOT/admin/functions/foo.bar.php
```

You probably want

```
$.ajax('/ROOT/functions/foo/bar.php');
```

With that leading `/`, the browser ignores ALL of the subdirectory stuff in the url and uses the entire path from the ajax call as the entirety of the path.

```
http://example.com/ + /ROOT/functions/foo.bar.php
```

Comment: /ROOT/functions/foo/bar.php' worked for me, I'm not sure why I can't use relative paths in XAMPP but It's causing the problem as I tried a live version and the relative paths work fine.